# Export JasperReports to XSL (Excel) or DOC (Word)

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, jasper-reports

I have a situation. I want to generate a report and open it in another window in the JSF platform using JasperReports framework. Right now, I am able to generate the PDF version of the report. The following is the JSF view for the report:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <h:outputText value="#{lang.member}: *" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu converter="memberConverter" value="#{memberProcesListBean.member}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{lang.memberGroupIntroduction_memberGroupName_req_txt}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{lang.select}..."/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{memberProcesListBean.memberMenu}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="#{lang.startDate}: *" />
                    <p:calendar pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" required="true" requiredMessage="#{lang.defaultProcesses_defaultDate_req_txt}" value="#{memberProcesListBean.startDate}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="#{lang.endDate}: *" />
                    <p:calendar pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" required="true" requiredMessage="#{lang.defaultProcesses_defaultDate_req_txt}" value="#{memberProcesListBean.endDate}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="#{lang.metalCode}: *" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu converter="metalCodeConverter" value="#{memberProcesListBean.metalCode}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{lang.memberGroupIntroduction_memberGroupName_req_txt}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{lang.select}..."/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{memberProcesListBean.metalCodeMenu}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="#{lang.reportFormat}: *" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="ReportFormat" value="#{memberProcesListBean.fileFormat}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{generalInfoBean.fileFormatsList}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

                </h:panelGrid>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <h:commandLink value="Download" action="#{uyeIslemListesiBean.retrieveReport}" target="_blank" />
```

However, I weren't able to retrieve and open in another window in the Excel and Word formats of the report. Should I change something in the view segment?

Yours sincerely...

Answer (score -1):

I shouldn't say this, but there is a plugin that may help you to achieve that: [JasperReports JSF Plugin](http://jasperreportjsf.sourceforge.net/web/index.html). Take a look to its documentation and check if it fits your needs. But I would do, basically, is replace your  for a . Since the report is generated in a secondary request you can still bind it to the values of your backing bean, maybe, by means of a [custom report source](http://jasperreportjsf.sourceforge.net/web/sources/others.html).